# How to select rows only if column values are same?

Tags: sql

I have a table like below

```
City   Status
a       y
a       y
a       y
b       n
b       n
b       y
c       y
c       n
d       n
d       n
```

I want the result to be returned as

```
City   Status
a       y
a       y
a       y
d       n
d       n
```

Group by city but whose all status value should be same for that city.

How can I do this?

Comment: tried groupby, distinct but not getting correct result. It is returning records with diff. status as well.

Comment: what is the DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.city = s.city AND
                       t.status <> s.status)
```

Comment: Sagi,it didn't work for multiple cities. Always it returns records related to city 'a', not returning records related to city 'd'

Comment: You're doing something wrong, this query should work @ShilpaBharkhada

Comment: Got it.City column char length issue.Resolved. Thanks your query worked.